# Updating kubernetes deployment will create new pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have an existing kubernetes deployment which is running fine. Now I want to edit it with some new environment variables which I will use in the pod. 
Editing a deployment will delete and create new pod or it will update the existing pod.
My requirement is I want to create a new pod whenever I edit/update the deployment.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep Pods with old configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is always going to recreate your pods in case you change/create env vars.

Lets check this together creating a deployment without any env var on it:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Let's check and note these pod names so we can compare later:

```
$ kubectl get pod 
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-56db997f77-9mpjx   1/1     Running   0          8s
nginx-deployment-56db997f77-mgdv9   1/1     Running   0          8s
nginx-deployment-56db997f77-zg96f   1/1     Running   0          8s
```

Now let's edit this deployment and include one env var making the manifest look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        env:
          - name: STACK_GREETING
            value: "Hello from the MARS"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

After we finish the edition, let's check our pod names and see if it changed:

```
$ kubectl get pod 
nginx-deployment-5b4b68cb55-9ll7p   1/1     Running   0          25s
nginx-deployment-5b4b68cb55-ds9kb   1/1     Running   0          23s
nginx-deployment-5b4b68cb55-wlqgz   1/1     Running   0          21s
```

As we can see, all pod names changed. Let's check if our env var got applied:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti nginx-deployment-5b4b68cb55-9ll7p -- sh -c  'echo $STACK_GREETING'
Hello from the MARS
```

The same behavior will occur if you change the var or even remove it. All pods need to be removed and created again for the changes to take place.

Comment: Thanks @mWatney for the clear answer with an example.

Comment: Please, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer. Happy to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a new pod, then you need to create a new deployment for that. By design deployments are managing the replicas of pods that belong to them.